# Not all control paths return value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Why does Visual Studio shows me that error with following code:

```
    int func( int a )
{
    if ( a < 0 )
        return -a & 3;
    else if ( a > 0 )
        return a | 8;
    else if ( a == 0 )
        return 10;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement before the function scope ends. What's actually unclear about that error message?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the compiler is not clever enough.:)

Try to change the body of the function the following way

```
if ( a < 0 )
    return -a & 3;
else if ( a > 0 )
    return a | 8;
else 
    return 10;
```

Also you can place a comment after else as it is adviced by **@buc**

```
if ( a < 0 )
    return -a & 3;
else if ( a > 0 )
    return a | 8;
else /* a == 0 */ 
    return 10;
```

Comment: I usually also comment the condition on the last else clause, it makes easier to understand the code later: `else /* a == 0 */`

Comment: @buc I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler isn't smart enough to realize that one of your three cases has to be hit. The better way to write it is:

```
int func( int a )
{
    if ( a < 0 )
    {
        return -a & 3;
    }

    if ( a > 0 )
    {
        return a | 8;
    }

    // a must be 0
    return 10;
}
```